# configure django apscheduler with apache & mod wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, apscheduler

I have configured django apscheduler in django project by running the below command -
***python manage.py runapscheduler***

but now we have moved the application to the production server and configured with Apache & Mod wsgi so now how to configure and run apscheduler.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: I believe you can do the same way. Activate your virtual env and then run the same command

Comment: how i can do in apache. running the command explicitly will be temporary solution. is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@mrgrantanderson/replacing-cron-and-running-background-tasks-in-django-using-apscheduler-and-django-apscheduler-d562646c062e explains how to set an AppConfig that includes the scheduler:

For that, you have to add the following to your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "django_apscheduler",
]

# This scheduler config will:
# - Store jobs in the project database
# - Execute jobs in threads inside the application process
SCHEDULER_CONFIG = {
    "apscheduler.jobstores.default": {
        "class": "django_apscheduler.jobstores:DjangoJobStore"
    },
    'apscheduler.executors.processpool': {
        "type": "threadpool"
    },
}
SCHEDULER_AUTOSTART = True
```

The file that starts your scheduler may look like this:

```
import logging

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import register_events, register_job

from django.conf import settings

# Create scheduler to run in a thread inside the application process
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(settings.SCHEDULER_CONFIG)

def start():
    if settings.DEBUG:
        # Hook into the apscheduler logger
        logging.basicConfig()
        logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Adding this job here instead of to crons.
    # This will do the following:
    # - Add a scheduled job to the job store on application initialization
    # - The job will execute a model class method at midnight each day
    # - replace_existing in combination with the unique ID prevents duplicate copies of the job
    scheduler.add_job("core.models.MyModel.my_class_method", "cron", id="my_class_method", hour=0, replace_existing=True)

    # Add the scheduled jobs to the Django admin interface
    register_events(scheduler)

    scheduler.start()
```

And the AppConfig that will start the scheduler like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "core"

     def ready(self):
        from . import scheduler
        if settings.SCHEDULER_AUTOSTART:
            scheduler.start()
```

(all code copied from the tutorial linked above).

Note however, that django-apscheduler states in their README that

*The tradeoff of this simplicity is that you need to be careful to ensure that you only have one scheduler actively running at a particular point in time.* (https://github.com/jcass77/django-apscheduler#quick-start).

If you run the scheduler productively in a multithreaded Django-Environment, this is not guaranteed as far as I understand it. So this solution should definitely be taken with a grain of salt - the more proper way would be to follow the suggestion of the README and make a blocking command for the scheduler and to run that independently of what you're serving in a dedicated process.